# Spivak Chapter 11 Corollary 3 Converse

Tags: real-analysis

In Calculus by Michael Spivak, Corollary 3 to the Mean Value Theorem (Chapter 11) is given as:

> If $f'(x) > 0$ for all x in an interval, then $f$ is increasing on the interval; if $f'(x) < 0$ for all $x$ in the interval, then f is decreasing on the interval.

He then goes on to say the converse of this corollary is false, giving the example of $f(x)=x^3$, for which $f'(x)\geq0$ for $x\geq0$. However, this does not mean that $f(x)$ is increasing at $x=0$.

But this seems like the wrong example, because Corollary 3 never mentions the derivative being equal to 0. So what would be a counterexample of the converse of Corollary 3 that does not involve the equals sign?

Comment: It's non sence talk about being increasing or decreasing at single point. You must specify and interval or a set with more of two elements. By the other hand the definition of increasing function it's not have positive derivative is. If we have $x\geq y$ then $f(x)\geq f(y)$. Being increasing is a consequence of $f'>0$ not the definition of being increasing. Not all increasing functions have derivatives well defined.

Comment: The example is correct. The function $f(x)=x^3$ is (strictly) increasing for $x\geq0$, but we can not conclude that $f'(x) > 0$ for $x\geq0$, because $f'(0) =0$.

Comment: In fact, we can also consider the function  $f(x)=x^3$ for $x \in [-1,1]$.  Then $f$ is is (strictly) increasing for $x \in [-1,1]$, but we can not conclude that $f'(x) > 0$ for $x \in [-1,1]$, because $f'(0) =0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simplify, suppose that the corollary just states that:

> If $f'(x)>0$ for all $x$ in an interval, then $f$ is increasing on the interval.

Then the converse would be

> If $f$ is increasing on an interval, then $f'(x)>0$ for all $x$ in that interval.

And the example$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&[-1,1]&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R\\&x&\mapsto&x^3\end{array}$$shows indeed that the converse doesn't hold.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What is that notation called, that you used to define f at the end?

Comment: I don't think that there is a name for it.